# Reference namespace from main project

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, namespaces, vb.net-2010

I have a project which has a reference to a "Utilities" project. The "Utilities" project references a 3rd project. All have the same namespace, but I can't do a "using OurNamespace.Utilities.3rdProject" from the main project.

I need to keep it so that all other new projects, only has to reference the "Utilities" project and have access to all other namespaces referenced through it. I can't include all the references on all projects.

/edit (it cascades sort of)

Main Project (references Utilities)
        -- Utilities
                 -- Project with same namespace referenced by Utilities

In Main project, I now need to be able to access the namespace in the project that is referenced within Utilities reference, but without adding it to the main project exclusively.

***Edit***
"Project 1" references Utilities

```
using Utilities.Namespace1;
```

Within Utilities another project is referenced with Namespace2

I want to now access Namespace2 from "Project 1"

```
using Utilities.Namespace2;
```

Without having to exclusively reference BOTH in "Project 1" seeing as there will be multiple projects referencing Utilities

Comment: what is the exact problem u are facing??

Comment: I'm not sure what problem your facing, are you saying you want to reference a project with the child namespace and not include the parent namespace?

Comment: I can't reference the 3rd project's namespace from my main project by only referencing the "Utilities" project (which has the 3rd project's reference in it)

Comment: If you need to access both the Utilities project and the 3rd Project, ensure both are sharing the same names spaces.  You will still need to add reference to the dll.

Comment: That's the point of the question, I'm trying to avoid that so that my "Utilities" handles all the references and any other project that references my "Utilities" has access to any other namespace that falls within it and/or it's referenced projects

Comment: it's as @Kami said. i think if you want to access functionallity from your third project without referencing it, you'll have to expose it through some sort of interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to directly use components of an assembly in another assembly, then you need a reference. By "directly" I mean in a strongly-typed way, e.g.:

- Creating an instance of a type in the other assembly.
- Handling instances of types in the other assembly.

In contrast, "indirect" use is if the Utilities assembly uses the components of 3rd project in the background, but does not publish these e.g. through public properties, arguments of public methods and so on.
To clarify further on assemblies and namespaces: one does not reference namespaces, but assemblies. Namespaces are only used to make type names unique. Namespaces and assembly names are completely independent from each other from a technical perspective (though it is good practice to start the namespaces with the assembly name). So having the same namespace in two assemblies, does not change the situation in any way; if you want to use the types of the other assembly, you still need a reference.
In order to solve your issue, you can either add the reference to 3rd project or if you can't do that, do one of the following:

- Add wrappers in the Utilities assembly for the required functionality in the 3rd project. As you already have a reference to the Utilities assembly, you can access these wrappers - as long as you do not access the types of 3rd project directly.
- Create another intermediate project that contains the wrappers and reference this.

Comment: Thanks, how would a wrapper for the 3rd project look like? In this case, I'm using Dapper.NET as my 3rd project that is referenced by my Utilities project. I've tried writing something to the effect you have suggested, but to the impact of throwing away functionality from the original code that I would like access to

Comment: I marked your suggestion as an answer. I created a wrapper that just have to expand over time instead of dropping in the functionality as is